# Post repeating with infinite scroll

Tags: php, posts, jquery, javascript

I'm working on this page: http://bit.ly/1ujkiFa

I'm creating an infinite scroll of books (wordpress posts). 
If you see the first row of books is this one:

[image]

**But if you scroll down, after it "loads more books", then this books appears again.**

So it's always loading the books (wordpress posts) from the start, not loading the posts continuosly.

Any idea where is the problem?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="infinite-scroll">
<div id="infite-activities">
 <div class="row">
          <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
          $args=array("post_type"=>"books","posts_per_page"=>"12");
           /*  $args["paged"]=( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; */
            $args["paged"]=$paged;
            if(is_single())
                $args["orderby"]="date";
          $books=new WP_Query($args);
           while($books->have_posts()):$books->the_post();?>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
              <div class="book-grid-img">
                  <?php $default_attr = array('class'   => "img-responsive");?>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail("books-grid",$default_attr);?></a>
              </div>
              <div class="box-desc-book">
                  <div class="book-title">
                     <?php the_title();?>
                     <span><?php the_field("autor");?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="book-download">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">MORE INFO</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile;?>

          <div class="pagination">
             <?php
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
                    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
                    'total' => $books->max_num_pages
                ) );
                ?>
         </div>

      </div>


<script>
jQuery('#infinite-scroll').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
    finishedMsg: "<em>No more books.</em>",
    msgText: "<em>Loading more books</em>"
    },
    navSelector     : "a.next",
    nextSelector    : "a.next",
    itemSelector    : "#infite-activities",
    debug           : true,
    dataType        : 'html',
    maxPage         : 5,
    path: function(index) {
        return "page/" + index + "/?test=1";
    }
}, function(newElements, data, url){

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your itemSelector must be that what makes each one item, in your case it isn't #infinite-activities. And I'm sure you have wrong also navSelector and maybe nextSelector.

Comment: So how should I change it?

Comment: For first change your pagination to classic http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Comment: changed it to `<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>` and now the infinite scroll doesn't work :(

Comment: It's wrong, you must call next page, not next post. You need <div class="paginationtion"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>, no previous_post() and next_post(). Now is navSelector: ".pagination" and set also your new nextSelector.

Comment: @Medardaosa ok, changed to it. but infinite scroll not working still. I put this: `<div class="pagination"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>` and changed infinite scroll: `navSelector   : ".pagination"` and `nextSelector  : ".pagination"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19339/discussion-between-medardaosa-and-diego).